# Pre-commit hook permission denied inside script

Tags: bash, git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I have following pre-commit hook:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

result=''

for file in $(find rest/src/main/groovy/ru/naumen/modules -name '*.groovy' | sort); do
    filename=basename "$file"
    result+=echo "${filename//.groovy/}",
done

result+='smpUtils'

sed -i -r "s|modules = .*|modules = $result|g" rest/smpsync.ini

git add rest/smpsync.ini
```

I'm getting `Permission denied` error on line 8

```sh
filename=basename "$file"
```

And I'm not able to determine the reason of it.

Hook itself has execution rights (`chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit`)

Whole directories/files tree in `./rest/src/main/groovy/ru/naumen/modules` has read/write rights and belongs to my user.

Comment: `filename=basename "$file"`  you need a `$( )`  but also can be done with P.E. `filename=${file##*/}`

Comment: But that is not the only problem, try this site for validating shell scripts.  https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
filename="$(basename "$file")"
```

In order to get the result of the [*command* `basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) in your `filename` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Issue #1 was as mentioned by @VonC in variable assignment

`filename=basename "$file"` -> `filename=$(basename "$file")`

Issue #2 was in line #9 (I just removed `echo`):

`result+=echo "${filename//.groovy/}",` -> `result+="${filename//.groovy/}",`